# How to use Github API to get all users of a Repository?

Tags: github, github-api

I can see all the members of a repository using Github.

For example: [Members](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/network/members) of Kundera.

Is there any way to get this list using Github API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that "members" view really shows repository forks. You can use the [list forks API endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#list-forks) to see them, e.g.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/impetus-opensource/Kundera/forks
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a github project for getting User Details (name, company, location, email) of users (*Subscribers, Stargazers, those who Forks*) of a Git Repository.

All you need to provide **Organization Name, Repository Name**.

```
List<UserDetail> userDetailList = GitUsersDetails.getUserDetails(ORG_NAME, REPO_NAME, UserType.SUBSCRIBERS);
```

`UserDetail` Entity:

```
public class UserDetail {

    private String name;

    private String company;

    private String location;

    private String email;

   // Getters & Setters
}
```

> check project [here](https://github.com/devender-yadav/GitUserDetailsFinder).